# Worauf bezieht sich "den" hier?

Tags: pronoun

Aus Der Zauberberg Von Mann:

> Der Raum, der sich drehend und fliehend zwischen ihn und seine
>   Pflanzstätte wälzt, bewährt Kräfte, die man gewöhnlich der Zeit
>   vorbehalten glaubt; von Stunde zu Stunde stellt er innere
>   Veränderungen her, die **den** von ihr bewirkten sehr ähnlich sind, aber
>   sie in gewisser Weise übertreffen.

Sollte *den* nicht *denen* sein, wenn es ein Relativpronomen für *die Änderungen bewirkten* von *Zeit* ist?

English version:

> Space, rolling and revolving between him and his native heath,
>   possessed and wielded the powers we generally ascribe to time. From
>   hour to hour it worked changes in him, like to **those** wrought by time,
>   yet in a way even more striking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Den* ist kein Relativpronomen, sondern Artikel eines impliziten zweiten *Veränderungen*, das weggelassen wurde:

> ... von Stunde zu Stunde stellt er innere Veränderungen her, die den von ihr bewirkten [Veränderungen] sehr ähnlich sind, aber sie in gewisser Weise übertreffen.